# Parse a text file with no newline using RegEx

Tags: regex

I have a text file like below. Every record has 12 fields which are separated by `|`, but there is no record delimiter like a newline, and every record starts with `555`. I am trying to parse it with RegEx.

**555**`|abc|user|2|20120914055204696|20120914055204718|0||||21|33`**555**`|def|udp|2|20120914055204696|20120914055204718|0||||22|33`**555**`|abc|user|2|20120914055204696|20120914055204718|0||||23|33`

I tried with `555(\|.*?\|){12}(\d\d)`, but it did not work. Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: Why? Open your favourite text editor and replace 555 with \n555, then parse it with your favourite CSV library. It will take many fewer hours of headbashing if you can't write the regex quickly. (You will then have an easy time of counting the fields per record, and checking whether 555 appeared in a field value).

Comment: Try this `555(?:\|[^|]*){11}(?=555\||$)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
555(?:\|[^|]*){11}(?=$|555)
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/zX7dM1/1)

It will match these records in the input string:

```
555|abc|user|2|20120914055204696|20120914055204718|0||||21|33
555|def|udp|2|20120914055204696|20120914055204718|0||||22|33
555|abc|user|2|20120914055204696|20120914055204718|0||||23|33
```

The regex `555(?:\|[^|]*){11}(?=$|555)` matches:

- `555` - literal `555`
- `(?:\|[^|]*){11}` - 11 occurrences of `|` followed by any number of characters other than `|`
- `(?=$|555)` - up to (but not returning as part of the match) end of string or `555`.

Comment: Does it work for you? Please let me know if you need more assistance with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
555(?:\|[^|]*?){11}\d\d
```

You need to remove the second `|` .See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/sS2dM8/31